# How to display an animated picture in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to display an animated picture, whatever its format, in Flutter. The fact is that currently there seems to be only one solution available, video_loader. This works only on full screen, but it doesn't fit my use case.

Any idea on how I could sort this out?

Comment: Sorry to hear you are blocked. Can you please "thumbs up" this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/204 and leave a comment with your use case? Thanks!

Comment: Already did :)  But I'll leave a comment

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll keep that in mind. But to be honest, this had a purpose. The 'urgent' here was to avoid an answer such as linking to a Pull Request that is still not yet ready for production (because there is one).   What is the proper way to ask the question is this situation ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Now, Image widget Supports GIF. (April 18)

For Ex.

`new Image(image: new AssetImage("assets/ajax-loader.gif"))`

Comment: I am getting this error when displaying gifs: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/painting/multi_frame_codec.cc(108)] Could not getPixels for frame 21 on Android and similar errors on IOS

Comment: @UpaJah Is there any way to play this GIF only once?

Answer (score 42):

You can split the frames into separate images using https://ezgif.com/split and add them as assets in your pubspec.yaml.

Then use an `Animation<int>` to select the correct frame to display. Make sure to set `gaplessPlayback: true` to avoid flickering.

For example, the following code displays the frames of an [animated GIF](https://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/images_blogs/design/2013/09/tumblr_inline_mqutgxtW2Z1qz4rgp.gif) that was created by Guillaume Kurkdjian.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData.dark(),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<int> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = new AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 5))
      ..repeat();
    _animation = new IntTween(begin: 0, end: 116).animate(_controller);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _animation,
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
              String frame = _animation.value.toString().padLeft(3, '0');
              return new Image.asset(
                'assets/frame_${frame}_delay-0.04s.png',
                gaplessPlayback: true,
              );
            },
          ),
          new Text('Image: Guillaume Kurkdjian', style: new TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this is one of my favorite answers on Stack Overflow

Comment: Sadly, it's not one that is likely to have a long shelf life. If you're from the future and [animated GIF support](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/204) is implemented, please use that instead!

Comment: It seems animated images in Flutter currently only support infinite looping. This solution was helpful for me to provide programmatic start and restart functionality to animated images (`_controller.forward`, `_controller.reset`).

Comment: This is still a fantastic answer even after animated gif support shipped in Flutter. I used this excellent example to figure out how to do a a 2 frame animation where the end frame is dynamically set via UI. thanks @CollinJackson !

Comment: how to run it once instead of looped animation?

Comment: @temirbek remove the `..repeat()` part from the controller.

Comment: Removing the `...repeat()` does not loop the animation once! Does anyone know how to repeat it only once??

Comment: @genericUser hint: try to set a global variable as boolen playedOnce or smthng else, check that boolean is true in animated builder (just a hint, not tested if it works)

Answer (score 6):

**2021 Update**

As of now flutter does supports playing `gif` files using the `Image` widget.

```
Image.asset('assets/logo.gif')
```

But there's a problem with current way of loading `gif` in flutter. The `gif` plays in a loop and you can't stop the `gif` after playing it once. There are other ways of showing animated pictures using Rive and [Lottie](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie) and both of them comes with a pretty well maintained flutter package that gives lots of features out of the box.

**Workaround :**

1. Convert your gif to mp4 ([Gif to mp4](https://ezgif.com/gif-to-mp4))
2. Convert mp4 to Lottie json ([Mp4 to Json](https://observablehq.com/@forresto/video-to-lottie))
3. Upload your Lottie json to [lottiefiles.com](http://lottiefiles.com) or add to your `assets` folder
4. Use [Lottie package](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie) to load your animation

Example from [Lottie package](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie) docs :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            // Load a Lottie file from your assets
            Lottie.asset('assets/LottieLogo1.json'),

            // Load a Lottie file from a remote url
            Lottie.network(
                'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xvrh/lottie-flutter/master/example/assets/Mobilo/A.json'),

            // Load an animation and its images from a zip file
            Lottie.asset('assets/lottiefiles/angel.zip'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For sure this is not the most ideal way of loading a gif as this is just a workaround. You can simply use an `Image` widget if you're not doing much with your `gif`. But if you will use Lottie then you get lots of things that you can do with your gif with much more control.

Answer (score 1):

**In order to run gif animation only once, there are 2 solutions.**

First solution.

```
List<int> listGifDuration = [0,0,22,26,31,27,30,29,29,23,29,24,25,27,33,33,29,29];
List<int> listGifDurationDs = [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,2,5,0];
List<double> listGifFrames = [0,0,315,389,310,294,435,423,425,331,425,360,365,395,309,384,426,435];
strgif = "assets/gif/motion-all.gif"
fetchGif(AssetImage(strgif)).then((value)  {
 controller= GifController(vsync: this,duration: Duration(seconds: listGifDuration[widget.storyid]));
 controller.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
 TickerFuture tickerFuture = controller.repeat(min:0,max:listGifFrames[widget.storyid],period:Duration(seconds: listGifDuration[widget.storyid]));
              tickerFuture.timeout(Duration(seconds: listGifDuration[widget.storyid]), onTimeout:  () {
                controller.forward(from: 0);
                controller.stop(canceled: true);
              });
        });
```

2nd solution.

Convert the property of the gif file from the infinite loop to 1 loop.

Please use following link to convert gif file looping count.

https://ezgif.com/loop-count

and then

```
child: new Image.asset(strgif),
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use Image widget to load any type of image whether it is a normal image or the gif.

We can load them from our asset as well as from network with the help of Image widget

```
Image.asset('name');
Image.file(file);
Image.memory(bytes);
Image.network('src');
```

There are some dependency for load the gif also