# How can we control animated gif image using button?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to control the gif animation by clicking the button i.e., If I pressed the 'click me' button animation start and again pressing animation should stop.  I am taking reference for this question [How to display an animated picture in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46519260/how-to-display-an-animated-picture-in-flutter#) 

I don't want to split the gif images into frames, I have to use only one gif image and control only that. Here is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<int> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = new AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 3))
      ..stop();
    _animation = new IntTween(begin: 0, end: 7).animate(_controller);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _animation,
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
              String frame = _animation.value.toString().padLeft(0, '0');
              return new Image.asset(
                'assets/lips.gif',
                gaplessPlayback: true,
              );
            },
          ),
          new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text('click me'),
            onPressed: () {
              if (_controller.isAnimating) {
                _controller.stop();
              } else {
                _controller.repeat();
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This isn't possible today, unless you decode all the frames into individual images yourself.

Comment: Workaround : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65822669/6915572

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Flutter supports playing `GIF` files using [`Image`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html) widget.

But there is still no easy way to control (e.g pause and play) the `GIF` files. When it comes to controlling it, one of the workaround is to use a package. [Lottie for Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie) could be use to implement this behavior.

> Workaround :
>
> - Convert your gif to mp4 ([Gif to mp4](https://ezgif.com/gif-to-mp4))
> - Convert mp4 to Lottie json ([Mp4 to Json](https://observablehq.com/@forresto/video-to-lottie))
> - Upload your Lottie json to [`lottiefiles.com`](http://lottiefiles.com/) or add to your `assets`
>   folder
> - Use Lottie package to load your animation

Try to check this tutorial from Medium: "[Explore Lottie Animation In Flutter](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/explore-lottie-animation-in-flutter-6989389e8286)".

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to manipulate GIF playback using Flutter's Image widget. However, you can try using [flutter_gifimage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gifimage) plugin - this allows you change the GIF's playback speed and control the frames displayed on screen.