# Flutter, replaying GIFs

Tags: flutter, dart

Im making a simple RockPaperScissors app in which i am using a gif for the hand animations.

Everything works fine the first time the animation is being played, but if you wish to play the gif the second time

(e.g. choosing the rock two times in one instance)

then it only display the start frame of the gif and doesn't replay it.

Heres the code:

Widget:

```
new Image(
          image: gameInstance.getPlayer1Choice(),
          width: 500.0,
          height: 500.0,
         )
```

On click function :

```
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
            gameInstance.play(
               kRPSValues['rock']['game_value'],
             );
     });
  },
```

The play() function simply assigns a key to a var _userChoice (0 to 2, each key representing either rock, paper or scissors)

The getPlayer1Choice() function

```
 ImageProvider getPlayer1Choice() {
return AssetImage(user1ChoiceImage[_userChoice]);
```

}

and the user1ChoiceImage cosnt:

```
const user1ChoiceImage = {
  0: "assets/paper-animation.gif" /*paper*/,
  1: "assets/stone-animation.gif" /*rock*/,
  2: "assets/scissors-animation.gif" /*scissors*/
};
```

Is there a way to make the gif start from the beginning every time the img src is changed?

To summarise :

- if you choose rock the first time, it plays the whole gif, then if you choose paper - it plays the whole gif but if you choose the a gif that has been played already the second time twice, e.g. rock again it shows just a static image of the first frame of the gif

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46519260/how-to-display-an-animated-picture-in-flutter#) - does precisely what I wanted to do, the only downside is that you have to split the gif into multiple frames

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51775

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    image.evict();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a lot of work to create again the animations from scratch, but i suggest you to check you the flutter_flare package:

https://pub.dev/packages/flare_flutter

https://www.2dimensions.com

You can create an account, create the animations from their web client (multiple sequences) and import and call the sequences from your flutter app assets.

I have them working on several projects for custom loaders.
Hope it helps.